# how to compare float and string values

Tags: tableau-api

Now I have problems for the tableau data type, my aim is to add the value 30000 for the TX of the RCA-2015, which is the last line.

Now the system tells me that :

```
 1.Can't compare float and string values

 2.Can't mix agggregate and non-agggregate in if  expressions
```

The copq value which I use is a dimension I create.

I'm sorry that I can't share my workbook with you because it's confidential.

[image: Screenshot]

PS:  How can i share  the twbx file to you guys?..

PS:[Sheet (fORM_COPG)], [COPO_Value($)] contains a list of numbers

Answer (score 0):

You are using the IF-ELSE syntax in incorrect way. Use it like this

```
IF [Doc. Number (TIL, etc)] = "RCA-20150520-1775" AND [Contrat_Type]!="CSA"
THEN "3000"
ELSE ATTR([Sheet (fORM_COPG)], [COPO_Value($)])
END
```

If you can share the TWBX file, I might be able to look into it. Screenshots of error doesn't help much.

Comment: thank you sir,in fact i tried to correct it just like yours,but it tells me that <<expected  type string,found float>>,i'm confused about it

Comment: From your screenshot,  I see all used variables are string only except `Sheet1 COPQ` value. What datatype is that? Can you share the TWBX file ?

Comment: ok i have the file,can you tell me how can i share it to you?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your formula:

1. You can't use comparision in `Then` part, Comparison can only be used in `If`.
2. 3000 and ATTR are not same hence you shouldn't use in If and Else, Since If and Else should return same datatype.

You need to explain what does `[Sheet (fORM_COPG)], [COPO_Value($)]` contains and why are you hardcoding If value and else value is dynamic.

Best suggestion would be attach the workbook in any of the free uploading sites provided data is not confidential, Else you can use google drive or drop box as everyone does